# Sum of size of distinct set of descendants $d$ distance from a node $u$, over all $u$ and $d$ is $\mathcal{O}(n\sqrt{n})$

Tags: trees, upper-bound

Let's consider a rooted tree $T$ of $n$ nodes. For any node $u$ of the tree, define $L(u,d)$ to be the list of descendants of $u$ that are distance $d$ away from $u$. Let $|L(u,d)|$ denote the number of nodes that are present in the list $L(u,d)$.

Prove that the sum of $|L(u,d)|$ over all distinct lists $L(u,d)$ is bounded by $\mathcal{O}(n\sqrt{n})$.

## My work

Consider all $L(u,d)$ such that the left most node on the level $Level(u) + d$ is some node $v$. The pairs $u, d$ for all such $L(u,d)$ must be distinct and the sum of all $d_i$ will correspond to the number of nodes $x$ in the tree with $Level(x) \le Level(u) + d$.

This is because if some sequence of nodes $v_1, v_2, \dots v_k$ corresponds to the descendants of some node $u$ at a distance $d$ and the sequence of nodes $v_1, v_2, \dots v_{k'}$ where $k' > k$ corresponds to the descendants of some node $u'$ at a distance $d+1$, then there must also exist a node $u''$ such that $L(u'', d) = v_{k+1}, v_{k+2}, \dots v_{k'}$. This would also mean that $u''$ is not in the subtree of $u$ and thus there are at least $d$ distinct nodes in the subtree of $u''$ upto a distance $d$ from $u''$.

If the distinct distances are $d_1, d_2, \dots d_k$ then, $n \ge \sum_{i}d_i \ge \sum_{i=1}^{k}i \ge \frac{k(k+1)}{2}$. =

$\implies k \le \sqrt{n}$

After this I tried to show that there can be only $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$ distinct lists $L(u,d)$ so that I can then trivially obtain the upper-boud of $n\sqrt{n}$ but I could not make any more useful observations.

This [link](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/81001/bittwist-editorial) claims that such an upper bound does exist but has not provided the proof.

Any ideas how we might proceed to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us start by giving an alternative formula for $\sum_{u,d} |L(u,d)|$. For a node $x$, let $\pi^{(d)}(x)$ be its $d$'th parent, and let $h(x)$ be its height. Then
$$
 \sum_{u,d} |L(u,d)| = \sum_x |\{ L(\pi^{(d)}(x),d) : 0 \leq d \leq h(x)\}|.
$$
It suffices to show that $|\{ L(\pi^{(d)}(x),d) : 0 \leq d \leq h(x)\}| = O(\sqrt{n})$ for all nodes $x$.

Let $y = \pi^{(d-1)}(x)$ and $\pi(y)$ be $y$'s parent. If $L(\pi(y),d) \neq L(y,d-1)$ then $y$ must have a sibling $z$ with a leaf at depth $d$. We can associate the $d$ vertices on the path leading to the leaf (including $z$) to $\pi(y)$; note that vertices associated to different parents of $x$ are distinct.

For each element in $\{L(\pi^{(d)}(x),d) : 0 \leq d \leq h(x)\}$ choose a representative $\pi^{(d)}(x)$ with the maximal $d$, and let $I$ be the set of all such $d$'s. In particular, if $\pi^{(d)}(x)$ is a representative then $L(\pi^{(d)}(x),d) \neq L(\pi^{(d-1)}(x),d)$, and so $\pi^{(d)}(x)$ has $d$ vertices associated to it. We deduce that
$$
\sum_{d \in I} d \leq n.
$$
In particular, $I$ can contain at most $\sqrt{n}$ numbers larger than $\sqrt{n}$, and so $|I| = O(\sqrt{n})$.